# Trying to hand data to functions from an .on() map

Tags: jquery

I'm currently working on some JQuery code which will make it so that tooltips appear next to the user's mouse when they mouse over certain objects. There's about 13 unique tooltips, each of which has a number of different triggers. I'm just having a bit of a trouble figuring out a way to pass data to my functions so that I don't have to create 13 sets of nearly-identical functions with different identifiers. Here's the code I'm using, which works but requires being copied multiple times:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

function phpTooltipPosition(event) {
    var phptooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
    var phptooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
    $('#marpole').css({top: phptooltipY, left: phptooltipX});
}

function phpMethod(event) {
    $('#marpole').removeClass('hidden')
    phpTooltipPosition(event);
}

function phpHide() {
    $('#marpole').addClass('hidden');
}


$('.marpole').on({
    mousemove : phpTooltipPosition,
    mouseenter : phpMethod,
    mouseleave: phpHide
});
});
```

When I was reading up on this I read that using an event map for .on() makes it so that you can't pass data to functions... is there a workaround for this?

Comment: so its the same function with different IDs passed in?

Comment: yeah, there would be a different class of items that would trigger a tooltip with a different ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try to code in this style to help you separate out your logic vs. events:

```
// Ensures code inside this function is called once jQuery is loaded.
jQuery(function() {

    $('div').click(function() {
        functionToCall.apply(this, arguments);
    });

});


var functionToCall = function() {
    // Actual code here
};
```

If you're needing multiple events from one master event, you can use jQuery's `.on()` function to handle that as well.

```
$('#outer-wrapper').on('click', '.div-you-want-evented', function() {
    // Actual code here
})
```

I think that answers your question?  Not 100% sure what you were needing based on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id into your functions.

```
$('.marpole').on({
    mousemove : function(event){
        phpTooltipPosition(event,$(this));
    },
    mouseenter : function(event){
        phpMethod(event,$(this));
    },
    mouseleave: function(event){
        phpHide(event,$(this));
    }
});
```

And then use it!

```
function phpTooltipPosition(event,$item) {
    var phptooltipX = event.pageX - 8;
    var phptooltipY = event.pageY + 8;
    $item.css({top: phptooltipY, left: phptooltipX});
}
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: I tried this method out, but for some reason it didn't work. Thanks for your suggestion, though (I had been trying a few ways to go the route you're using here myself). In the end I ended up going with the very shameful route of making unique functions for each class.

Comment: I just realized I did it a really stupid way ... calculating the ID and then passing it in, when I could have gone the easier and less code route of just passing in the jQuery object. i understand the need to just make it work, but when you get some down time i REALLY recommend you clean it up. it wont be as hard as you think.